# Move Windows 10 Bootmanager from one SSD to another

Tags: windows-10, boot, bootloader

I would need some support one a boot issue with my Windows 10 system.

I bought a larger SSD some time ago and reinstalled Windows 10 on the new SSD. It seems it was a big mistake to do the installation, during the old SSD was still in the system. During boot still the old SSD is used but starts Windows on the new SSD. I want to remove the old SSD now, but it will not boot without it.

I am also not sure if this can be done easily, because of the Recovery and EFI System Partition is on the old SSD. Disk4 is the new one, Disk 5 the old one:

[image]

Would it be possible to fix it that way:

- shrink the Disk4  Win 10 Partition with the Disk Management tool.
- Move it the end of the free space (can this be done with the Disk Management tool?)
- Create / Copy over a recovery partition (is this possible?)
- Create / Cop over the EFI System partition (is this possible?)
- Crate the BootManager stuff with bcdedit

All of that without loosing the installation / data on the Disk 4.

I would know what to do on Linux, but I am not that certain on Windows anymore... :)

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Yes, you've made the typical mistake people do when they don't understand UEFI. Now, although there are Windows tools for what you want to do, reinstalling with only the new drive connected/enabled is by far much easier and probably faster. Later you can reconnect/re-enable the old drive and copy over your olod files or simply reformat it for other usages.

Comment: I don't think that reinstallation is required. It may be enough to reduce C, leaving, say, 600 MB of unallocated space, then disconnect disk 5 and do Startup Repair on disk 4.

Comment: @harrymc Sounds like a really good idea, but I'll leave 2GB of unallocated space at the beginning, just to be absolutely sure.

Comment: This might help - [link](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: @GabriellaGarcia regarding UEFI: guilty for sure. That's stuff I need about once a year and forget from occasion to occasion... But really want to avoid to reinstall.

Comment: @user375251 I know this is old post, but I am thinking about doing the same, so I wonder if startup repair helped?

Comment: @luvjungle unfortunately not. It got stuck somewhere. In meantime I gave up on this and will reinstall everything from scratch for several reasons... For sure I will take care where the boot information will be installed this time! :D

Answer (score 2):

After ignoring this issue for ages (nearly one and a half year obviously), I had a reason to bite the bullet and try again. I really needed the other SSD to install Proxmox and a VM.

The solution had been to create a new EFI partition on the SSD with the current/active Windows 10 installation. First I had to boot from the old installation. A recovery CD/DVD or USB key will do as well.

To [create a recovery drive](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-a-recovery-drive-abb4691b-5324-6d4a-8766-73fab304c246):

- Press the windows key and type: *create recovery drive* and select. Enter admin password
- select *back up system files to the recovery drive* and click *next*
- connect a USB driver and click *next*
- click *create* and wait a bit
- restart and enter the BIOS /EFI
- look out for boot options and select the newly create USB key
- save & exit

Now your system should reboot from the USB key. If not, try to use a USB connector directly on your motherboard.

To get some space on the SSD for the EFI partition we shrink the main partition, create a new EFI partition and write a bootloader to it by  doing following:

- Start a terminal with SHIFT-F10 during setup.
- open `diskpart`, [some more info](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/diskpart)
- list all the available disks with `list disk`
- `select disk X`, X is the one where the desired Windows 10 installation is located.
- `list partition`
- `select partition N`, the one to be shrinked
- `shrink desired=500`, let's shrink it by 500MB
- `create partition EFI size=200`
- `format quick fs=fat32 label="System"`, or maybe `label=EFI` if you like better?
- `create partition msr size=123`
- `exit`
- `bootrec /fixboot`
- `bcdboot c:\Windows /s b: /f all`, [some more infos if needed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bcdboot-command-line-options-techref-di).

For me this worked like a charm. Sometimes the pressure needs to be big enough to form diamonds. :)

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I wanted to add something that I had struggled with:
Make sure your actual windows install partition is mounted as C. I kept getting errors from bcdboot because, when I booted from a recovery disk, it mounted my old Windows partition (because I foolishly never formatted it) as C. in diskpart, find and select the volume by 'list volume' and `select volume <x>`, then `remove letter=C`. After that, find and select your install volume and `assign letter=C`. After that, you'll be able to run the last command in this post.