# Windows 11 UEFI - Issues Moving SSD BootManager

Tags: windows-11, uefi, efi, boot-manager, vhdx

Is anyone able to help fix boot manager issues when trying to (native) boot to vhdx once copied to a new partition on a new ssd?

I'm creating a new thread as my reputation prohibits me from commenting on the related article @ https://superuser.com/a/1648181/258643

I've had it working, but I now have a new ssd and am trying to update the boot manager.

The new SSD is installed as hard-drive 2, it's a windows 11 (tiny) build.

I've followed all possible steps, however

> bootrec /fixboot

Access is denied (from windowsPE / install usb)

The vhdx was copied (repeatedly, after retrying a few times after deleting partitions to try fix boot issues)
using **robocopy /j** (recommended for large files)

also at step 2 on [ms-instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/boot-to-vhd--native-boot--add-a-virtual-hard-disk-to-the-boot-menu?view=windows-11#step-2-apply-a-windows-image-to-the-vhd) I don't have install.wim so couldn't run
`Dism /Apply-Image /ImageFile:install.wim /index:1 /ApplyDir:V:\`
(Actually forget how I resolved on original install to native boot, other than using **diskpart** `convert gpt` to finally allow the install *into* the newly created vhdx

Current new disk (after removing partitions that still aren't bootable)
[image]

I'm able to clean and recreate partitions as instructed, and even recopy the vhdx, if anyone has any ideas. currently all recovery options at boottime are broken (auto repair fails)

I can see the new disk is a gpt (couldn't locate this info in diskpart from winpe)
[image]

As a last resort I'd attempted copying and updating the "working" bcd entry, and that's the only way I've got a new entry added to boot options (but not working).

I'm a little wary of attempting anything destructive until I know what I'm doing!
Hence no attempt to rebuild bcd...

TlDr the `bcdboot /fixboot` option looked like what I needed, but currently everything is too FUBAR to fix.

Am about to try steps outlined [here](https://www.diskpart.com/windows-11/repair-windows-11-uefi-bootloader-0725.html)   (just found whilst searching for **bcdboot access denied** ) - whilst trying from within normal windows (cmd:admin) the \efi\microsoft\boot folder is accessible, but `bootrec` isn't recognised in normal windows

▪ cd/d X:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\ (“X” is the letter you assign to the EFI volume)

▪ bootrec/fixboot

▪ ren BCD BCD.bak

▪ bcdboot C:\Windows /1 en-us /s x: /f ALL (Please change the content based on your own settings)

▪ bootrec /rebuildbcd

**bootrec** and **bcdboot** problems persist even from winpe.
ran chkdsk and no issues detected.

Tried checking some of the contents of the boot files in [system]:\efi\microsoft\boot, but they aren't human readable...

Officially stumped! Other than recreating ssd and reinstalling windows, all I can think is to try to fix dism (get install.wim.. maybe need another iso) or try third party app (something like paragon).

The new physical disk is disk0 , currently no recovery partition, suspected system partition issues (as not booting)

```
Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          931 GB   675 GB        *

  Partition 1    System             100 MB  1024 KB 
  Partition 2    Primary            256 GB   229 MB
```

Disk 1 is the old SSD, that has the VHD in use... I think on partition 5

```
 Disk 1    Online          119 GB  5645 MB   *    *

Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    System             100 MB  1024 KB
  Partition 2    Dynamic Reserved  1024 KB   101 MB
  Partition 3    Reserved            15 MB   102 MB
  Partition 4    Dynamic Data        69 GB   117 MB
  Partition 5    Dynamic Data        40 GB    69 GB
  Partition 6    Recovery             9 GB   109 GB
```

The VHD (C:) is disk 3 (volume 9) and it's partitions

```
 Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    System             100 MB  1024 KB
  Partition 2    Reserved           128 MB   101 MB
  Partition 3    Primary             34 GB   229 MB
```

Comment: What are you really trying to do? What does a new SSD have to do with vhdx boot?

Comment: move the vhdx to the new ssd, and update boot manager to boot from this.

test success: be able to rename the existing (original, copied) vhdx (proving it's not attached and currently in use as C: ) , once all traces are removed (so I don't have invalid boot entries), AFTER the new boot is working - currently can't boot to anything, except the vhd I'm trying to copy from (C:) - "vhd on bare metal" - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/boot-to-vhd--native-boot--add-a-virtual-hard-disk-to-the-boot-menu?view=windows-11#step-2-apply-a-windows-image-to-the-vhd

Comment: ... I'll then (eventually) open the laptop, replace the smaller, dying SSD, but for now happy to just "boot from #new# SSD 2" - in laptop

TlDr upgrade from  128GB SSD to 1TB SSD, with OS sitting as a file on a partition on new SSD

Comment: Can you rewrite your question with Disk and Volume identifiers? It's not very clear which you are targeting in different parts of your question. For a new SSD, you would usually follow the MS steps starting with step 3 while booted into winPE, and create a brand new BCD for the new disk - not update an existing one

Answer (score 0):

After repeating step 3 as advised I noticed bios was showing boot manager on sata 2, no mention of boot manager on sata 1 (new disk)

I was about to clean the new disk one last time,  but whist gathering screenshots and expecting load fail again when using f9 to get boot menu with sata 1, it worked.

Now how to make sata 1 be the first and default boot manager?!

[[image]

[image]

Comment: For HP computers, you usually hit F10 to open the bios options > System (or Storage) > Boot Options > Set your CT1000 to the first in order > Save+exit